# Default system mouse pointer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way I can change the default system mouse pointer from within my application and change it back to the original scheme when I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Cursor class to create a custom cursor, and you can set the mouse pointer to use that cursor while it's over your application.

Comment: I know that one.  What I really meant was I want to change the cursor from where we set it at Control Panal>Mouse>Pointers.